# How to create a parameter in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, attributes, request

How to create a parameter in JSP?
I want to make a parameter of `String` type. Are all parameters of `String` type only?
I have tried this:

```
 <% request.setAttribute("testID", "1"); %>
```

And this:

```
<% String testID="1"; %>
```

But on fetching value of parameter, through this:

```
String testID=request.getParameter("testID");
```

I am receiving `null`. How to fetch value of parameter `testID`?
Also, what is difference between `parameter` and `attribute`?

Comment: You should start by consulting the javadoc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that question, did not answered my question. How to set parameter?

Comment: Read more carefully. Parameters are either submitted through a form or through the query string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis give me a working solution. What to write inside JSP file?

Comment: Solution to what? Use a `<form>` and submit it or provide query strings in your request URL.

Comment: I used `<form>` but i am again receiving null. I used a hidden field inside it : `<input type="hidden" name="testID" value="1">`. I dont want to pass the value through query String in URL.
                                                                  `

Comment: you can try: jstl lib as <c:param name="parameterName" value="Value"/>. But remember import taglib first.

Comment: If you have a question about how to submit a `<form>` and you can't find results after doing extensive research, then ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you, however i want to ask is there any way to make hidden parameter using `<form>`? If yes, then how?

Comment: Put the `<input type='hidden' name='somename' value='thvalue'/>` inside the <`form>`.